# Non-nullable by default: how to enable the experiment?

Tags: dart

I just tried the following in DartPad:

```
void main() {
  int? x;
}
```

and get the following error:

```
Error compiling to JavaScript:
main.dart:2:6:
Error: This requires the 'non-nullable' experiment to be enabled.
```

1. How do I enable that experiment? I am using the Flutter SDK.
2. Does the experiment support null-safety static analysis already?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You enable the experiment by passing the flag `--enable-experiment=non-nullable` to the compiler or analyzer.

It is not a complete feature yet, so there are no promises about what it will do. Feel free to experiment, but don't use the flag for anything serious.

Comment: I could enable it. Works great. However, it complains that operator[] of Map never returns null and my checks are wrong. Is there already a Dart SDK with nullables applied?

Comment: No, the SDK has not been migrated yet.

Comment: How can we pass this too the compiler analyzer then. For example with debug?

Comment: see answer from @mikyou here, the experiment is now call "non-nullable" instead of "nnbd"

Answer (score 18):

Add the following line to the analysis_options.yaml

```
analyzer:
  enable-experiment:
    - non-nullable
```

Answer (score 6):

Enable the non-nullable experiment with three steps:

1. Add dart-sdk version into pubspec.yaml

   ```
   environment:
     sdk: '>=2.8.0-dev.0 <2.8.0'
   ```
2. Add enable non-nullable experiment into analysis_options.yaml

   ```
   analyzer:
     enable-experiment:
       - non-nullable
   ```
3. Run your Dart code:

   ```
   dart --enable-experiment=non-nullable ./bin/hello_dart.dart
   ```

Answer (score 3):

For me, removing pubspec.lock and rerun fix the issue. I was importing the project from Windows to Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Manually removing `pubspec.lock` and running `flutter pub get` resolved the problem. In my case it was due to regression.