# Error: This requires the 'non-nullable' experiment to be enabled

Tags: flutter, dart

I am playing around with non-nullable types and added this to my `analysis_options.yaml`:

```
analyzer:
  enable-experiment:
    - non-nullable
```

I have a code-generator that is utilising the nullability extension. Visual Code is fine with my code.

Now, I try to run:

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner watch
```

I get this error message:

```
[SEVERE] Failed to snapshot build script .dart_tool/build/entrypoint/build.dart.
This is likely caused by a misconfigured builder definition.
[SEVERE] xyz.dart:95:7: Error: This requires the 'non-nullable' experiment to be enabled.Try enabling this experiment by adding it to the command line when compiling and running.
```

How can I pass `--enable-experiment:non-nullable` to `flutter packages pub run`?

The same happens if I run:

```
flutter build ios
```

I get the error message:

```
  lib/main.dart:61:26: Error: This requires the 'non-nullable' experiment to be enabled.

    Try enabling this experiment by adding it to the command line when compiling and running.
```

So, same question: How can I pass `--enable-experiment:non-nullable` to `flutter build`?

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40490, just linking it back here incase it gets updated

Comment: And have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/57605453/6668797

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non-nullable by default: how to enable the experiment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57598838/non-nullable-by-default-how-to-enable-the-experiment)

Answer (score 53):

This problem was occured for me after upgrading the Flutter.
I solved it by **cleaning and upgrading the project dependencies** again.
Run the below commands in the root directory of your project:

```
flutter clean
flutter packages pub upgrade
flutter pub run build_runner build
```

Also as others said, please make sure your sdk version in the `pubspec.yaml` is compatible with your flutter sdk version.

Comment: Also, sdk verision should be at least sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0" for that syntax

Answer (score 23):

For null safety to work,

```
environment:
   sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

should be this version at least.
then run `flutter clean`
and `flutter pub get` it will work.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
flutter clean
```

This is worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you're doing, sometimes it's as simple as changing the environment in your pubspec.yaml file to update the lower end, ie change a lower end like

```
environment:
sdk: ">=2.0.0 <3.0.0"
```

to

```
environment:
sdk: ">=2.6.0 <3.0.0"
```

or

```
environment:
sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
```

This has worked for the various things that cause this error (using spread syntax in latest version of flutter and dart will also cause this), but I don't need the older environments.

Answer (score 0):

> A simple fix for me was to ensure that the analysis_options.yaml is in
>   the root folder. In my case, it was in the lib folder and none of the
>   experimental features worked until I moved the file to the same folder
>   as pubspec.yaml. Other things that can happen include updates that
>   make the experimental feature no longer required so updating to the
>   latest version on the flutter master channel may be useful in addition
>   to verifying the file location. Haven't been able to get the command line 
>   running with this option, however.

- [Dart Reference](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#the-analysis-options-file)
- [Example of Analysis Options File](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/analysis_options.yaml)

Answer (score 0):

### The problem will be solved easily, Do these things | rAhMaN

1. If you have upgraded Flutter then downgrade your flutter sdk use the command in flutter_console.bat "flutter downgrade" it reverses your SDK package.
2. Again in which after completion run the command "flutter pub upgrade"
3. Check your IDE and run "flutter pub get"
4. If the again give issue then check your dependency that is highly recommended for your project like all Firebase packages, http, provider, and many more. Manage your dependency according to the console panel issue or use the command "flutter pub downgrade". Your problem will be 100% solved.
5. After doing that if you faced this issue again it means you have not followed the guidelines correctly that I have told you.