# How to find pubspec yaml of Dart file to fix null safety issue?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I am experimenting with the new null safety update in Dart.

This is my code where I'm using ? to initialize a null variable.

```
void main() {
  int? a;
  a = null;
  print('a is $a.');
}
```

It works fine on Dartpad. However, VS code shows an error saying

```
This requires the 'non-nullable' language feature to be enabled. Try updating your pubspec.yaml to set the minimum SDK constraint to 2.10.0 or higher, and running 'pub.get'.
```

The main purpose of this main.dart file is for me to just practice on some code, hence a pubspec.yaml file doesn't exist in the root folder since this isn't really a whole Flutter app project. How do I find or create the pubspec file?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57605453/12828249)

Comment: Recommend creating a new project with `flutter create` command. This will set all your files up. Then you will have the pubspec.yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I find or create the pubspec file?

Just create a new file named `pubspec.yaml` in the root of your project (alongside the `bin` folder). You can use the following content:

```
name: my_project_name
version: 1.2.3
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'
```

This sets the minimum SDK version to v2.12 which will automatically enable null-safety. See https://dart.dev/null-safety for more info.